# Are the Star Trek Discovery uniforms seen anywhere else in TOS canon?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, star-trek-uniforms, star-trek-discovery

So now that we have a teaser trailer ([US trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dxe_ugmIVM), [Netflix trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzIHhFcZ3Wc)), is there any indication that these uniforms are simply upgraded *Enterprise* uniforms, or is this pure "Abrams reboot"? They seem to bear little resemblance to the TOS or reboot uniforms

[image]

For comparison (the only other time we've seen blue uniforms as the standard)

[image]

Comment: This is pure Abrams reboot style. The uniforms (and the tech) are completely anachronous.

Comment: This trailer is pure trollbait. The free-standing holograms, the callback to Nemesis, the JJ Abrams style monitors, the lens flare. It's all designed to make loyal trekkies hate the show.

Comment: @Valorum I suddenly want a reboot of _Voyager_ captained by Jar Jar Binks. He might be better than Janeway.

Comment: @MolagBal - I'm keeping an open mind about Discovery but it's hard, real hard to cope with the fact that this looks like complete cack.

Comment: Your video is not available; it'd also be nice if you included a picture of the Discovery uniforms here, for easier comparison.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Yeah... boy they love their region locking. Anyways, they did publish a picture so I've added it

Comment: @Valorum:    Do you care about the stories or appearance?   If you think the look of TOS or TNG getting dated doesn't detract from those shows them you also shouldn't judge this one by its production design.   Stories above look cuts both ways.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - The stories are key but it would be nice if they didn't **go out of their way** to p*ss all over the established continuity.

Comment: I have a feeling that Discovery will go over about as well as "Shades of Gray" did.

Comment: Is the US trailer removed?

Comment: @IllidanS4 No, it's region locked to the US. The Netflix version is for internationals

Comment: @Machavity Thanks, I thought a video cannot be restricted to a region like this on YouTube. Well, that doesn't stop me, so in case anyone outside US wants to see the trailer (it's a bit different), I have [archived](http://31.31.77.202/archive/yt/#4dxe_ugmIVM) it.

Comment: Also from a comment in episode 3 it seems that on a pure science vessel the usual uniform seen has a blue colour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The costumes appear nowhere else in canon**

According to [this article](https://www.inverse.com/article/20416-star-trek-discovery-costumes-starfleet-uniforms-bryan-fuller-cosplay):

> Star Trek cosplayers are going to have to update their wardrobes very soon. Bryan Fuller revealed some major details about Star Trek: Discovery this week, and mentioned that the Starfleet crew members will be wearing “something completely different,” from previous looks.

Just as the costumes were often updated for each film or iteration of the TV Show, the costumes for Discovery were designed for that show, and have not appeared at any other time.

Comment: I wish they had kept the colors, though.

Comment: They did, but as metallic. Science blue became silver, Command Gold became metallic gold, and Ops red became Bronze/Copper.

Comment: @ench - To me it looked like there was a bluish tinge to the science officer's  striping.  Although it wasn't always obvious, depending on the lighting.